# Programmatically set allowed role on new taxonomy term

Tags: 9

i'm using the `permissions_by_term` module and I now want to programmatically create a term and set the `Allowed role` field value while doing this.

I create the term using this, and I added a line to show what I want:

```
$new_term = Term::create([
  'vid' => 'term',
  'name' => 'term name',
  //and then something like
  'allowed_role' => 'admin'
]);

$new_term->enforceIsNew();
$new_term->save();
```

This is not working, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into the code and search for the service that adds the role to the term. I think this could be `permissions_by_term.access_storage`. There is this function `addTermPermissionsByRoleIds`. Please take a look [here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/permissions_by_term/-/blob/3.1.x-dev/src/Service/AccessStorage.php#L335).

The script would look like.

1. Create the term programatically, fetch its id.
2. Find the roles' ids that you need to have the term access granted.
3. Call the service to do its job. Pass required arguments.